# C Program to calculate the length of the string using functions and character array

Tags: c, arrays, function, c-strings

I am writing a c program to caculate the length of the string using functions and character arrays.I had defined a function to calculate the length of a string. it returns the output as an int type. But i am getting the output as 0.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int stringLength(char);//function to calculate and return the string length

int main()
{
    char input[100],ch;
    int noCh,i=0;
    printf("\nEnter the string:\n");
    scanf("%s",input)
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        noCh=stringLength(input[i]);/*Passing each string character as input parameter to the function*/
    printf("\nThe number of characters in the string \"%s\" is %d.",input,noCh);
    return 0;
}

int stringLength(char output)
{
    int num=0;
    if(output ==" ")
        num--;
    else
        num++;
    if(output == EOF)
        return num;
}
/*output code*/
[Output code][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwvqQ.png
```

Comment: This code makes no sense, sorry. You might want to start with something simpler.

Comment: @Km Shrikanth It is unclear what the function stringLength should do.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the quick response. can you solve the problem? I need to get an input string from the user and i need to calculate the length of the string. The calculation part should be done in the function and the return the output as an integer.

Comment: @Km Shrikanth The function parameter int stringLength(char); is not a character array.

Comment: There is nothing to solve. A standard `strlen` is calculating the string length.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile.  Comparing a `char` with a string constant is meaningless.  And comparing it with `EOF` is probably meaningless as well, since `EOF` is an `int` value.  There's no loop in `stringLength`, and if the final `if` test is false, it falls off the end without returning anything (which should also be an error).  Start more simply.  Read about the C language, arrays, pointers, and strings.  Try to write a simple "Hello World" program.  Don't jump into the middle of something that you don't begin to understand.

Comment: @KmShrikanth, all you need to do is scan forward in `input` until you find the *nul-character* (e.g. `'\0'`, or equivalently just plain `0`). In `main()`, you can do that simply with `for (noCh = 0; input[noCh] != 0; noCh++) {}` or equivalently `noCh = 0; while (input[noCh] != 0) noCh++;`. Note `strlen` will be more efficient as it normally compares 4-bytes per-iteration rather than just 1.

Comment: Writing `c` is not a guessing game. Find a good tutorial and follow it in a pace you are comfortable with. Don't jump to the next lesson before you have understood the previous ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I didn't understand your function. I have written a much simpler code for this.

The first thing which I felt is wrong about your code is that you are passing a character as your function argument for calculating the no of characters in the string.

You should pass the entire array as an argument to the function.

```
int stringLength(char *);//function to calculate and return the string length

int main()
{
    char input[100],ch;
    int noCh,i=0;
    printf("\nEnter the string:\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    /*
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        noCh=stringLength(input[i]);/*Passing each string character as input parameter to the function*/

    noCh = stringLength(input);
    printf("\nThe number of characters in the string \"%s\" is %d.",input,noCh);
    return 0;
}

int stringLength(char * output)
{
    /*
    int num=0;
    if(output ==" ")
        num--;
    else
        num++;
    if(output == EOF)
        return num;
    */
     int count = 0;
     char *ch = output;
     while(*ch!='\0')
      {
           count = count +1;
           ch++;
      }
   return count;
}
```

Please have a look in this link [No of characters in string](https://www.programming9.com/programs/c-programs/191-c-program-characters-words-in-a-string) for better understanding.
Kindly have a look on this site  [how arrays are passed in function](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-passing-array-to-function-example/) as well.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense and will not compile.

Investigate this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t stringLength( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char input[N];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin );

    size_t n = stringLength( input );

    if ( input[n-1] == '\n' ) input[--n] = '\0';

    printf( "\nThe number of characters in the string \"%s\" is %zu.\n", input, n );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a string: Hello Km Shrikanth!

The number of characters in the string "Hello Km Shrikanth!" is 19.
```